# Python Multiprocessing/Multithreading -> 'Future' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I am getting this error, when using the "submit" functionality of ProcessPoolExecutor.

Exception has occurred: TypeError
'Future' object is not iterable
File "C:......\test3.py", line 28, in 
for f in as_completed(res):

```
import time
import json
import os
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import as_completed

BAN_API_URL = 'https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/'

def get_french_addresses(request):
    print(f"Started task with pid: {os.getpid()} fetch addresses: {request['search_field']}")
    query_params = {'q': request['search_field'], 'type': 'housenumber', 'autocomplete': 1}
    response = requests.get(BAN_API_URL, params=query_params)
    print(f"Finished task with pid: {os.getpid()} to address: {request['search_field']}")
    return json.loads(response.text)


request_data = [
    {'search_field': '17 rue saint maur'},
    {'search_field': '35 boulevard voltaire'},
    {'search_field': '32 rue rivoli'},
    {'search_field': 'Route de la Croqueterie'},
]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    # Execute asynchronously with multi threads
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        res = executor.submit(get_french_addresses, request_data)
        print(res)
        for f in as_completed(res):
            print(f.result())

    end_time = time.time()
    print(f'Total time to run multithreads: {end_time - start_time:2f}s')
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using [submit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit) which passes all of the data to the function at once, what you want is to use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) to pass it one item at a time, like so:

```
res = executor.map(get_french_addresses, request_data)
```

or if you need to keep using submit, you will have to split your data yourself:

```
res = []
with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for item in request_data:
            res.append(executor.submit(get_french_addresses, item ))
        print(res)
        for f in as_completed(res):
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, it can be done with "map" easily. but what if i wanted to use "submit". it is giving me error.  i need a solution with use  of "submit"

Comment: @Martin any breakthrough on this?

Answer (score 0):

the simplest edit to avoid the error, is to change

```
     for f in as_completed(res):
```

to

```
    for f in as_completed([res]):
```

However, this way it will almost be an equivalent of a synchronous call (I say 'almost' because some code still could execute between `submit` and `as_completed`, but because of GIL it should either be async itself or invoke some IO).

If you want the function `get_french_addresses` to return data asyncronously (as it processes it), it must be rewritten to support that.